# Missing ; before statement when I check response in Firebug?

Tags: xml, json, jquery

```js
var on_show_info_agile = function() {
    alert("aa");
    request_meta_info = $.ajax({
        url: search_metadata + current_doc_info.id,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: on_get_metadata,
        error: on_get_metadata_error
    });   
};
```

How can I resolve this issue? I tried changing `dataType` to `"script"`, I am getting the same error in firebug;

> missing ; before statement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="T">3</int><lst name="params"><str name="q">83779616</str><str name="callback">jsonp1308182704622</str></lst></lst><result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"><doc><str name="number">2716837</str><str name="itle">Wire</str><str name="name">Designated </str><str name="name">S.</str><date name="">2009-03-03T08:00:00Z</date><str name="claims">8</str><str name="id">810414</str><str name="name">D.</str><date name="date">2010-08-24T07:00:00Z</date><str name="_id">83616</str><str name="name">Non Provisional</str><date name="_date">2008-03T08:00:00Z</date><arr name=id"><str>3260</str><str>290</str><str>2510</str></arr><str name="_number">08CA</str><date name="te">201-03T08:00:00Z</date><str name="e">M</str><str name="">Application</str><str name="ry_code">CA</str><str name="ame">Canada</str><str name="_claims">74</str><arr name="inventors"><str>Kd D.</str><str>G</str><str>Pi</str></arr><str name="key">83</str><arr name="owne"><str></str></arr><arr name="tors"><str>d D.</str><str>G</str><str>Pai</str></arr><arr name="ers"><str></str></arr><str name="url"/></doc></result>

</response>
```

Above is the XML that I am getting but with the error. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Where have you placed the above code?

Comment: @Nix,I am working locally on my computer and search_agile_metadata is equal to (http://solrdev01:8800/solr-qcpatents/select/?q=). And If I am not specifying any dataType then I am getting this error
"XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal: "

Comment: From your comment here, it looks like the service is returning an XML, maybe you should try `dataType: 'xml'`

Comment: @Dhruva Sagar,@Dr.Molle: I tried with that... If I am using XML then I am not getting any response.. Then I am getting error "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:" but If I am using jsonp and script as a datatype then I am getting response but with the error "missing ; before statement"

Comment: @Raihan Jamal, perhaps your service is returning malformed JSON data ?

Comment: @Dhruva Sagar, I have checked the syntax of JSON... there is no problem in that.. As there are other threads also related to this problem... but I am not getting any help from them either..

Comment: @Raihan Jamal there's nothing wrong with this piece of code, however there is a lot of code that I don't know about so it's really difficult for me to tell

Comment: @Dhruva Sagar, what code you want me to post here..?

Comment: @Raihan: your JSON response would be appropriate.

Comment: @Andy E, then what can be the problem. As I am working locally on my comoputer.. not on the server.. that can be the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting XML, but telling jQuery that it's JSON with Padding.  It throws a syntax error because it is not valid JavaScript code and therefore can't be parsed as *JSONP*.

It's obvious that you're trying to obtain data from a different domain, which is why it doesn't work when you switch to XML.  For cross-domain requests, you need to look into [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) and IE's [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For support in older browsers, I'm afraid you're out of luck unless you can modify the resource to output valid JSON with padding.

Comment: if I am working on the server then this problem can be resolved?? And Any shortcut method to do this thing.. As It will take lot of time in reading all these.

Comment: @Raihan: If you're working on the same server/domain as the resource, then you won't have this problem, just switch the data type to `'xml'`.  If you want it to work from localhost, you'll need to look at the CORS stuff.